# Why is this .slideToggle function not working in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, I'm having some issues with the following code:

```
<div class="chat" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" class="chat-name" placeholder="Enter your name">
    <div class="chat-messages"></div>
    <textarea class="chat-textarea" placeholder="Type your message"></textarea>
    <div class="chat-status">Status: <span>Idle</span></div>
</div>
<div id="showmenu">Click Here</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
        $('.chat').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
</script>
```

As you can see, it should toggle the `.chat` div, but it does not.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: please post a fiddle ?

Comment: You have mis-matched closing braces, remove those and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/hshmrvLs/

Comment: @FrebinFrancis: Plop the code above into a fiddle (or better, a Stack Snippet), and it replicates the problem just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have an extra `});` at the end of the script. Remove it, and it works:

```html
<div class="chat" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" class="chat-name" placeholder="Enter your name">
    <div class="chat-messages"></div>
    <textarea class="chat-textarea" placeholder="Type your message"></textarea>
    <div class="chat-status">Status: <span>Idle</span></div>
</div>
<div id="showmenu">Click Here</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
        $('.chat').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
</script>
```

Your browser makes it *trivially* easy to diagnose bugs like this. Open the web console, and you'd see an error like

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

with a link to the line in question. In general, the fully-featured debugging tools built into the browser should be your first stop when trying to figure out what's going on (and what's going wrong) with your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the extra `})`

```
<script>
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
        $('.chat').slideToggle("fast");
    });
</script>
```

Wrapping this kind of code in DOM ready is a good practice.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
        $('.chat').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<script>
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
        $('.chat').slideToggle("fast");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ok @Regent i changed it